# How can I programm a layout like this?

Tags: android, xml, button, gridview, layout

I want to create a layout which looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/2a08bcd731fb1cfeb07e72f75bc05e7e
What should I use for this, that it fits to every device?

The screen is mine, but the problem is it does not fit to every screen size.
On some devices it looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/84d878061234c25ae872d4ed2491f2f4

Here is the code I used to pragramm this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Button"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Button"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Button"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Button"/>

              //and 200 buttons more

    </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How can I programm a layout like this which fits on every screen size?
Important is the ScrollView

Comment: Search for `GridAdapter` for `Gride view` or `RecyclerView` with custom adapter

Comment: Is it possible to do that without writing any code in the Activitys? I only want that arrangement of the buttons

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean but it can be one using `GridAdapter` just like what you do with a `ListView` and Also can be achieved by using `RecyclerView` AFAIK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thought that came to mind is to use RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager

```java
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

This will give you a list going down vertically with 2 columns. You probably want to check out CardView as well if you don't mind, but sometimes I like to use them together.

Once you've written the adapter for your RecyclerView you can set the GridLayoutManager and YourAdapter in your activity and that's pretty much the only thing you'll actually need in your activity: initialize the adapter, set the layout manager and adapter of your recyclerview, and done. You need to write the adapter yourself, but there's a lot of tutorials that you can Google.

[Here is a link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) that I think I've followed before when I started learning about RecyclerView. It was sometimes ago so I'm not sure if it is still correct, but you can check it out as a start.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without writing any code in the Activitys? I only want that arrangement of the buttons. Later then i'm going to use the onClick method to use the Buttons. So I ONLY want the arrangement of the buttons. Is there a easier way?

Comment: I honestly don't know. But using RecyclerView you can write as little as maybe less than 10 lines of code to initiate them in activity. The majority of the codes are going to be in the Adapter and the ViewHolder(and you can add your onClickListener in there as well).